# Paamayim nekudotayims in PHP 5.2

Tags: php-5.2

I can upgrade php 5.2 in my server. I have to make this server work today (the vacation I have planned tomorrow is under question because of this error) with new testlink. I am stuck with following error i.e Paamayim nekudotayims.

What changes I should do to resolve it?

[This link](http://www.aypwip.org/webnote/Testlink%252520Error) contains the file with the bug.

Comment: what's exactly the error (what file and line number)?

Comment: You can find the file or complete codes , here in this link http://www.aypwip.org/webnote/Testlink%252520Error   

Error line number is 37

Comment: that link only gives one file and there's no error (according to php) in that file alone. The problem could be in one of the required files.

Comment: Line number 37 ,  $info['cfg'] = '<pre><xmp>' . $iname::getCfgTemplate() . '</xmp></pre>';

:: is the error , which I want to replace with ->

Answer (score 0):

The Scope Resolution Operator (also called **Paamayim Nekudotayim**) or in simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.

SO may be in your codes you try to call static method or properties with wrong operator.

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator):

> In PHP, the scope resolution operator is also called Paamayim
>   Nekudotayim (Hebrew: פעמיים נקודתיים‎), which means “double colon” in
>   Hebrew.
>
> The name "Paamayim Nekudotayim" was introduced in the
>   Israeli-developed Zend Engine 0.5 used in PHP 3. Although it has been
>   confusing to many developers who do not speak Hebrew, it is still
>   being used in PHP 5, as in this sample error message:
>
> $ php -r :: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
>
> As of PHP 5.4, error messages concerning the scope resolution operator
>   still include this name, but have clarified its meaning somewhat:
>
> $ php -r :: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::'
>   (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)